# Broken font rendering with fixed element in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, font-face

Safari 9 changes font rendering if there is an element with `position:fixed` present. In particular, font appears thinner than it should be.

Without fixed element: https://jsfiddle.net/4rLmqwfo/

With fixed element: https://jsfiddle.net/ys0ehofq/

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
body { -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; }

Comment: For some reason it does work on example I provided, but on real project font became even worse

Comment: Also, font becomes bolder in Chrome

Comment: it seems that both of the examples are the same